# OPC UA Server .Net Standard

Tags: .net, .net-core, namespaces, nodes, opc-ua

I'm new to programming (C#) and OPC UA.
I'm using UA-.NETStandard-Samples
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/tree/master/Samples . I notzed that NetCoreConsoleServer doesn't define NameSpace or Nods. And I'm trying to create/ define a NameSpace or add Nodes to the Server (detailed steps).

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the [boiler server example](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Opc.Ua.Sample/Boiler). The [BoilerNodeManager.cs](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Opc.Ua.Sample/Boiler/BoilerNodeManager.cs) file contains the code sections to create Namespace, Nodes and add them to the Server Address Space.
Hope this answers your question.

If you are looking for any other hands-on information on OPC UA, you can also check out the open62541 stack (C stack | Mozilla License | Embedded ready | TSN ready):

- Free documentation: You can look at the open-source documentation page: https://open62541.org/doc/current/
- Paid online course: Practical introduction to OPC UA – code walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack: https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes it helped.

another question, how to create my own model, my own Nodes and PredefinedNodes.xml?
I've already created a Sample using UA-Modeler, and exported the .xml and xsd files. but didi't got the PredefinedNodes.xml,  got this error " 'Could not resolve namespace uri: http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd' "